# how to disable change detection on a specific test level

Tags: angular

I have a component that resets certain variables to null on ngOnInit. (Note that if I am move the variable resetting to the constructor of the component, it works great but since I didn't write the component in the first place, I am curious to see if changeDetection can be turned off on a test by test case from the spec file.) That is affecting one specific test which needs a variable to pass but the variable is reset to null.

What I am hoping to get is in my test case to turn of fixture.detectChanges() but still set variable values from it that can be picked or that is not possible?

component:

```
export class TravelRequestComponent implements OnInit {

 fieldType : number = null;
 ngOnInit(){
 this.fieldType = null;

    }

setFieldType(fieldType){
  this.fieldType = fieldType
 }
processForm(){
    console.log(this.fieldType); //null all the time
   if(this.fieldType){
      //process form
  }
  else{
   this.toastr.error("","Select Field Type");
  }

 }

 }
```

setFieldType is called from a dropdown element.

```
 beforeEach(() => {
  fixture = TestBed.createComponent(TravelRequestComponent);
  component = fixture.componentInstance;

//implementation
 fixture.detectChanges();
 });


it("should return the same user", ()=>{

  component.countiesList = MockData.Counties;
  component.fieldType = 1;
  fixture.detectChanges();
  component.processForm();
  });
```

Comment: Well, a pretty big part of the relevant code is missing. Then, looking at your code I don't think it's related to a change detection at all unless it is in the missing part of the code. So, I personally would rather start with the question "why do I need to do this in the first place"? This whole thing just doesn't sound right, but again - a big part of the code that is necessary to understand it correctly is missing.

Comment: @AlexanderLeonov the demand by my manager was that the correct toastr message is shown for each error message.

Comment: Well, this is a high-level requirement. It absolutely doesn't mean that you need to deal with change detection on such a low level. Furthermore, using some 3rd-party toaster (for example, angular material components or angular bootstrap) should mean exactly that you don't have to deal with change detection. And parts of the code that I mentioned in the first comment are still missing.